# SVN merge -c merges zero files

Tags: svn, merge

I'm trying to merge a few specific commits from one branch (A) to another (B). A was created as a branch from B some time ago, and then different commits happened on both. Neither are the trunk.

I do

```
svn merge -c 42 http://server/A
```

when standing in a directory in a freshly checked out version of B. The commit I'm trying to merge has refid 42.

I then get the following output:

```
--- Merging r42 into '.':
 U   foo/bar
 U   foo
 U   .
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r42 into '.':
 U   .
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r42 into 'foo':
 G   foo
--- Eliding mergeinfo from 'foo':
 U   foo
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r42 into 'foo/bar':
 G   foo/bar
--- Eliding mergeinfo from 'foo/bar':
 U   foo/bar
```

But when I check things with `svn status` the only changes I see is in mergeinfo, the actual contents of the commit were never committed.

I'm 99.9% sure that the patch has not been introduced by some other means (manual insertion etc.)

Comment: Meanwhile, we decided to brute force the changes from branch A onto B, as A will be a dead end from here on. Still annoying that our VCS is actively working against me.

Answer (score 1):

Try merge with option --ignore-ancestry

Comment: That just gives me: `svn: E200004: Cannot merge automatically while ignoring mergeinfo`.